# How to notify user when programatically adding them to a group

Tags: c#, sharepoint, csom

I am adding members to a group with the code below.

My question is very simple :

**When adding members with this code, the invited person does not get an email notifying them. However when doing the same from the UI there is an option to notify the user. How can I do that from the code?**

```
public void UpdateGoupMembers(string groupName, List<string> loginNames)
{
    using (var clientContext = new ClientContext(baseUrl))
    {
        clientContext.Credentials = credentials;
        var web = clientContext.Web;

        var group = web.SiteGroups.GetByName(groupName);

        if (group != null)
        {
            foreach (var loginName in loginNames)
            {
                var user = web.EnsureUser(loginName);

                if (user != null)
                {
                    group.Users.AddUser(user);
                }
            }

            var existingUsers = group.Users;

            clientContext.Load(existingUsers, includes => includes.Include(
                f => f.LoginName,
                f => f.UserId,
                f => f.PrincipalType,
                f => f.Email,
                f => f.Id));

            clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

            foreach (var existingUser in existingUsers)
            {
                var userName = existingUser.LoginName.Split('|')[2];
                if (!loginNames.Contains(userName))
                {
                    group.Users.RemoveByLoginName(existingUser.LoginName);
                }
            }
        }

        clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not believe it is possible to send a Welcome Email when users are added to a group programatically based off of the method [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/ee539274(v%3Doffice.14)).

However, you can use the CSOM library to send an email programatically to the specific user after adding them to the group. [Send Emails via SharePoint CSOM](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/q/177607/75930) will be a great reference on how to do this.